# Optimize slow query

Tags: mysql, innodb, performance, linux, query-performance

I have this query that takes over half an hour to run on our Linux MySQL db...

```
SELECT 
    ls.emailaddress
    , lse.subscriberid
    , lse.eventtype
    , count(lse.eventtype) as total 
FROM list_subscriber_events as lse
    LEFT JOIN list_subscribers as ls ON
        lse.subscriberid=ls.subscriberid AND
        ls.subscriberid<>'' AND 
        lse.subscriberid<>'' AND 
        ls.subscriberid NOT IN (select subscriberid from stats_emailopens) AND
        ls.subscriberid NOT IN (select subscriberid from stats_linkclicks) 
GROUP BY 
    lse.subscriberid 
HAVING COUNT(lse.eventtype)>10 AND COUNT(lse.eventtype)<25 ;
```

What can I do to make it faster? All thoughts welcome...

Indexes exist for subscriberid on both tables. Table schema are as follows based on InnoDB - my.cnf uses 70% ram for buffers on a 16gb machine:

```
mysql> describe list_subscribers;
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| subscriberid         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| listid               | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | 0       |                |
| emailaddress         | varchar(200) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| domainname           | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| format               | char(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| confirmed            | char(1)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| confirmcode          | varchar(32)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| requestdate          | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| requestip            | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| confirmdate          | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| confirmip            | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| subscribedate        | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| bounced              | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| unsubscribed         | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| unsubscribeconfirmed | char(1)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| formid               | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| fbl                  | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+----------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
17 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> describe list_subscriber_events;
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| eventid      | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| subscriberid | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| listid       | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| eventtype    | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| eventsubject | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| eventdate    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lastupdate   | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| eventownerid | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| eventnotes   | text    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The two stats tables are:

```
mysql> describe stats_emailopens;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| openid       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| subscriberid | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| statid       | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| opentime     | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| openip       | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| fromlink     | char(1)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| opentype     | char(1)      | YES  |     | u       |                |
| country_code | varchar(255) | NO   |     | -       |                |
| country_name | varchar(255) | NO   |     | -       |                |
| region       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | -       |                |
| city         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | -       |                |
| share        | varchar(255) | NO   |     | n       |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe stats_linkclicks;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| clickid      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| clicktime    | int(11)      | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| clickip      | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| subscriberid | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| statid       | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| linkid       | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| country_code | varchar(255) | NO   |     | -       |                |
| country_name | varchar(255) | NO   |     | -       |                |
| region       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | -       |                |
| city         | varchar(255) | NO   |     | -       |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

With an explain extended added I get:

```
+----+--------------------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table      | type  | possible_keys                                                   | key                               | key_len | ref                                | rows    | Extra                           |
+----+--------------------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | lse        | ALL   | list_subscriber_events_subscriberid_idx,subscriberid            | NULL                              | NULL    | NULL                               |   25033 | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY            | <derived2> | ref   | <auto_key0>                                                     | <auto_key0>                       | 4       | andersen_database.lse.subscriberid |     113 | NULL                            |
|  2 | DERIVED            | ls         | index | NULL                                                            | subscribers_email_list_idx        | 607     | NULL                               | 2848473 | Using where; Using index        |
|  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | sl         | ref   | stats_linkclicks_subscriberid_idx,stats_linkclicks_subscriberid | stats_linkclicks_subscriberid_idx | 5       | andersen_database.ls.subscriberid  |       1 | Using index                     |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | se         | ref   | stats_emailopens_subscriberid_idx,open_statid_subscriberid      | stats_emailopens_subscriberid_idx | 5       | andersen_database.ls.subscriberid  |       1 | Using index                     |
+----+--------------------+------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------+------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------+
5 rows in set, 3 warnings (0.03 sec)
```

The warnings comprise

```
 Note  | 1276 | Field or reference 'andersen_database.ls.subscriberid' of SELECT #3 was resolved in SELECT #2  
 Note  | 1276 | Field or reference 'andersen_database.ls.subscriberid' of SELECT #4 was resolved in SELECT #2 
 Note  | 1003 | /* select#1 */ select `ls`.`emailaddress` AS `emailaddress`,`andersen_database`.`lse`.`subscriberid` AS `subscriberid`,`andersen_database`.`lse`.`eventtype` AS `eventtype`,count(`andersen_database`.`lse`.`eventtype`) AS `total` from `andersen_database`.`list_subscriber_events` `lse` left join (/* select#2 */ select `andersen_database`.`ls`.`subscriberid` AS `subscriberid`,`andersen_database`.`ls`.`emailaddress` AS `emailaddress` from `andersen_database`.`list_subscribers` `ls` where ((not(exists(/* select#3 */ select 1 from `andersen_database`.`stats_emailopens` `se` where (`andersen_database`.`ls`.`subscriberid` = `andersen_database`.`se`.`subscriberid`)))) and (not(exists(/* select#4 */ select 1 from `andersen_database`.`stats_linkclicks` `sl` where (`andersen_database`.`ls`.`subscriberid` = `andersen_database`.`sl`.`subscriberid`)))))) `ls` on((`andersen_database`.`lse`.`subscriberid` = `ls`.`subscriberid`)) where 1 group by `andersen_database`.`lse`.`subscriberid` having (count(`andersen_database`.`lse`.`eventtype`) > 10) |
```

Comment: `ls.emailaddress` might be "functionally dependent" on the value of `lse.subscriberid` so it would be OK in that case. I am more concerned about the "raw" `lse.eventtype` in the columns list as you count it and even expect the count to be `> 10` - are all those values supposed to be exactly the same? If not then there is no guarantee which one will be picked and it might even be a different one in each execution,

Comment: @Del check the execution plan of queries you need to analyze with [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) - add the results for this query to your question (after you fix it). Please use `show create table <name>;` instead of the `describe`.

Comment: jkavalik, yes, the lse.eventtype should be exactly the same in each case. The emailaddress will always have the same subscriberid so they are "functionallty dependent".

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

Comment: Your EXPLAIN does not match the SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this returns the expected result?

`lse.subscriberid` in both `stats_emailopens` and `stats_linkclicks` are NULLable, so `NOT IN` is dangerous. Try to replace it with `NOT EXISTS` or add `WHERE subscriberid IS NOT NULL` to both subqueries.

Comparing INTEGERs to '' (`ls.subscriberid<>''`) is useless...

Finally you might try to move some joins into a Derived Table:

```
SELECT 
    ls.emailaddress
    , lse.subscriberid
    , lse.eventtype
    , count(lse.eventtype) as total 
FROM list_subscriber_events as lse
    LEFT JOIN 
     (
       select ls.subscriberid, ls.emailaddress
       from list_subscribers as ls 
       where not exists
          (select * from stats_emailopens as se 
           where ls.subscriberid = se.subscriberid)
         AND not exists
          (select * from stats_linkclicks as sl 
           where ls.subscriberid = sl.subscriberid)
     ) as ls
    ON lse.subscriberid=ls.subscriberid
GROUP BY 
    lse.subscriberid 
HAVING COUNT(lse.eventtype)>10 AND COUNT(lse.eventtype)<25 ;
```

Comment: That is a lot faster dnoeth - there just seems one anomaly in the results, ls.emailaddress sometimes appears as NULL in the resulting rows (with the rest of the row containing valid details - if I look up the subscriberid in the lists_subscribers table, it has a valid email address)

Comment: You LEFT JOIN, of course there might be NULLs returned, that's why I asked if you're sure this is the correct result.